# How many server does this kind of website needs

Tags: php, windows, linux, web, hosting

I am planning to run a website that host big files (around 200mb total is 2TB of files), I want to run a website that support multiple user downloading such file, I estimate there will be 100 user simultaneously downloading, for not letting down the user, I estimate that each user will get approximately 30Kb-200Kb of speed for downloading.

In above scenario, what kind of requirements I need? Like hardware, internet connection and OS and software? I plan to host it using linux+php, 
1. How many servers will it take? Is 1 enough?
2. What is the server spec?
3. How much speed should I subscribe?
4. I know only basic php, can you help me to list out PHP/other software that can limit sending bandwidth to user (trying to be fair to user and care for server), and also PHP/other software that can send out file with ability to disable download resume, cookie/session generated link (temporarily link that will be invalid in a period of time), IP checking, etc.
5. Any idea where is cheap dedicated server hosting?

If I were to use windows server, do you think it will have better/same performance with linux? because from what I know, usually those successful sites that serve big files are usually in linux?

Please guide me to run my own dedicated web server.